# Passing constructor arguments in the NewContractCreation in go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-deployment, evm

I am trying to create a transaction to deploy a contract using the `types.NewContractCreation()` method in the core folder of go-ethereum. However I don’t understand how to pass the parameters of the constructor in the data field. Should I just join the byte code and the parameters in byte format? Or is there a preferred way to do it?

Any help appreciated